# Shifting z values of all features in a shapefile?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

I have a few line and polygon shapefiles that have the wrong z vertex values. I need to apply the same z shift for all features in all the shapefiles.

I looked around and only managed to do it by loading the data in a PostGIS database and running the following SQL script on every layer:

```
UPDATE public.poly
SET geom = ST_Translate(geom, 0, 0, 10)
```

Is there an easy way to shift z values of all features in a shapefile in QGIS, even if it involves using PyQGIS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do it from command line with ogrinfo http://www.gdal.org/ogrinfo.html by utilizing the SQLite/Spatialite SQL dialect http://www.gdal.org/ogr_sql_sqlite.html which allows you to use all the Spatialite functions http://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/spatialite-sql-latest.html.

```
ogrinfo -dialect sqlite test.shp -sql "update test set geometry=ST_Translate(geometry,0,0,10)"
```

Result of this test:

```
ogrinfo test.shp -al
INFO: Open of `test.shp'
      using driver `ESRI Shapefile' successful.

Layer name: test
Metadata:
  DBF_DATE_LAST_UPDATE=2017-04-12
Geometry: 3D Polygon
Feature Count: 1
Extent: (327.000000, 228.000000) - (630.000000, 631.000000)
Layer SRS WKT:
(unknown)
OGRFeature(test):0
  POLYGON Z ((327 497 10,447 631 10,630 498 10,381 228 10,327 497 10))
```

Comment: I'll hold on accepting this answer for a while, although it solves my issue, in the hope that someone might come up with a PyQGIS solution as I tried sifting through the API docs but only found info about shifting X and Y.